# SSRS Report - 'Go to URL' not working. Link does nothing

Tags: ssrs

I have a report that I moved from one location to another.  The report has several 'Go to URL' links and the location of the files has changed from the original report.

The files I am trying to link to are here: `D:\Mobility\BuildManifests\Scooter`.

In SSRS, the `Go to URL` function is:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('"
    + "file:\\D:\Mobility\BuildManifests\Scooter" 
    + "\" 
    + Fields!BuildManifestPDFFileName.Value
    + "','_blank'))"
```

I don't have much experience with this. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Is the report it's pointing to still correct and available to the user running the report?

Comment: Well its not pointing to a report its pointing to pdf files

Comment: Question still stands is it accessible?